# Kion signifas "malpermesantaj" kaj la dikita frazo?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, meaning-in-context

> 2 Diru al la Izraelidoj jene:Se iu pekos per eraro kontraŭ la ordonoj
>   de la Eternulo, **malpermesantaj** fari diversajn aferojn, kaj li
>   faros iun el ili; 3 se pastro sanktoleita pekos, **ĵetante kulpon sur
>   la popolon**, tiam li alportu pro sia peko, kiun li pekis, bovidon
>   sendifektan al la Eternulo, kiel oferon propekan. (Biblio, Levidoj
>   4:2,3)

Mi komprenas la dikitan frazon tiele: `La pastro pekos kaj lia peko ĵetos sur la popolo.` Sed la Angla traduko estas: `If the priest that is anointed do sin according to the sin of the people;...`

Mi petas, ke oni klarigu ĝin al mi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La vorto *malpermesantaj* verŝajne referencas al la ordonoj. Do se oni disigas la frazon iomete, oni povus diri ĝin ĉi tiel:

> Estas ordonoj de la Eternuloj. Tiuj ordonoj malpermesas fari diversajn aferojn. Kontraŭi la ordonojn estas peko. Se iu tiel pekos per eraro kaj faros unu el la malpermesataj aferoj…

En la dikita frazo, *ĵetante* referencas al la pastro. Kiam estas aga vorto kun *-ante*, la aganto de tiu ago estas la sama aganto kiel tiu de la ĉefa verbo. En ĉi tiu okazo la ĉefa verbo estas *pekos*, kaj la aganto de tio estas *pastro*. Do oni povus disigi ĝin ĉi tiel:

> Se la pastro pekos, kaj li ĵetos kulpon sur la popolon, tiam li faru oferon kun bovido…

Ŝajnas al mi ke la angla traduko kiun vi citis ne multe kongruas kun tiu esperanta versio. Tamen mi vidas ke en la New International Version la traduko estas iom alia, kaj tiu ja ŝajne kongruas:

> If the anointed priest sins, bringing guilt on the people, he must bring to the Lord a young bull without defect as a sin offering for the sin he has committed.